# Get the data from date range

Tags: sql-server

I have a column TransationDate is decimal data type  the  data's like 20170121
I want to display data in date range, In my query it displayed only one record. what's wrong my query could any body advise to me.

```
declare @EndDate  varchar(10)
set  @StartDate   ='20170121'
set  @EndDate     ='20170129' 

SELECT  *
    FROM  LCOM.dbo.PORCPAH PORCPAH
    WHERE CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), PORCPAH.TRANSDATE), 112) >= @StartDate
    AND CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), PORCPAH.TRANSDATE), 112) <= @EndDate
```

Comment: and the issue is????

Comment: Always use the appropriate datetype, you've got a `date`, stored as `decimal` and compared as `varchar`. Why not just use a `date` datatype?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it

```
 declare @t table
(
dt decimal(30,0)
)
insert @t
values
(20150712),
(20160320),
(20160113),
(20170813),
(20180302),
(20160318),
(20171112),
(20180601),
(20160308),

(20180601),
(20180602),
(20180603),
(20180604),
(20180605),
(20180606)

declare @startdt varchar(20)='20180601'
declare @enddt varchar(20) = '20180606'

select *
from @t
where dt between @startdt and @enddt
order by dt
```

Comment: So you are aware, this is incredibly bad SQL practice.  Have a look at my updated answer to see how you should be using appropriate data types.  If you are storing your dates as `decimal` or `int` values you should reconsider this and if you cannot change that, you should *definitely* not be using `varchar` values as this will cause implicit conversions that will negatively impact your query performance.

Answer (score 1):

You are using `varchar` values instead of `date` values so your comparisons are obviously not going to work properly.  Use the appropriate data types and you will have a lot fewer issues:

```
declare @StartDate date = '20170121';
declare @EndDate date = '20170129';

select *
from LCOM.dbo.PORCPAH p
where p.TRANSDATE >= @StartDate
  and p.TRANSDATE <= @EndDate;
```

---

Using your other answer as a base, if you are using the appropriate data types to store your `date` values, this script has identical output to that in your script:

```
declare @t table(dt date);
insert @t values('20150712'),('20160320'),('20160113'),('20170813'),('20180302'),('20160318'),('20171112'),('20180601'),('20160308'),('20180601'),('20180602'),('20180603'),('20180604'),('20180605'),('20180606');

declare @startdt date ='20180601';
declare @enddt date = '20180606';

select *
from @t
where dt between @startdt and @enddt
order by dt;
```

Comment: As per your query  i got the same one record to get. Based on date range database have 9 records like

Comment: Transationdate                                                                                                20170121   .......................20170129   I need date ranged between these records.